# Error while sharing web link through whatsup , application not found in PC

Tags: html, whatsapp

I have the below code in website, when user click button , it should enable shares current url to whatsup but getting an error `application not found`.

```html
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=www.mywebsite.com/currenturl" data-action="share/whatsapp/share" target="_blank">
  <button>button<button/>
</a>
```

The error occurs in Win 7 machine and did not try in mobile

Comment: Your HTML is invalid,  you cannot have a button inside a link.

Comment: If it says the application isn't found, then presumably something is wrong with your installation of the Whatsapp application.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Did you ensure that WhatsApp is installed on that Windows machine?

Comment: I have whatsup open in browser but still the error persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine in mobile browser.

I was using Win 7 , whatsup does not support in it.

It support Win 8 and above.